# LightInject equivalent lifetime in .netcore DI container

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, light-inject

Migrating from 'LightInject' to .netcore DI container.

What are the **.netcore DI container** equivalents of below LightInject related registrations?

```
 a. container.RegisterConstructorDependency<IBar>((factory, parameterInfo) => new Bar()); 

 b. container.RegisterInstance<Func<string, string>>
        ((username, password) => new MemCache(userId, password, container.GetInstance<IBusinessLogic>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe A would be something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IBar>(container => new Bar());
```

For B, if you have an instance that already exists that you simply want to register, then you could do something like:

```
ISomething somethingInstance = new Something();
services.AddSingleton<ISomething>(somethingInstance);
```

But it seems like you actually want to register a factory, so I would suggest something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<Func<string, string, MemCache>>(ctx => (username, password) => new MemCache(username, password, ctx.GetRequiredService<IBusinessLogic>()));
```